# Why can't I add a user to a role in Atlassian's Jira?

Tags: jira, user-permissions, user-roles

I've created a new user and added them to the group "External Reviewers".  I've created a role of the same name and gone to the "Users and Roles" page for the project I want them to have access to.

But Jira won't show me ***any*** users or groups.  Even when I type in my own name or groups that have already been added to a role, Jira returns "No Matches".  This is true regardless of which project I am in.

(We use the cloud version of their software.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My user didn't have "Browse User" permissions.  I fixed this by assigning this permission to a high-level group that I belong to (in my case the "administrators" group).

This can be done by

1. clicking the little gear in the upper right going to "system"
2. on the left sidebar click through to "global permissions"
3. at the bottom of that page look for the "add permissions" form
4. select a reasonable group and assign them the "browse user" permission